# Error when running custom artisan command 'php artisan migrate:multiple'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

#### Laravel Version

9.52.16

#### PHP Version

8.1.4

#### Database Driver & Version

MySQL

#### Description

`2023_04_08_065850_create_business_categories_table` don't even exist in any of the migrations folder but still migrate command is trying to run this migration using custom artisan command `php artisan migrate:multiple` that I have created to run migrations from multiple folders in specific sequence.

**Error**

```
public_html$ php artisan migrate:multiple

   INFO  Preparing database.  
                                                                                                                                                         
  Creating migration table ............................................................................................................... 13ms DONE
                                                                                                                                                         
   INFO  Running migrations.  
   
 >>>>>>>>> Above Migrations of othe folders ran fine here
 
INFO  Running migrations.  
                                                                                                                                                         
  2023_04_07_065850_create_business_categories_table ..................................................................................... 30ms DONE
  2023_04_08_065850_create_business_categories_table ...................................................................................... 1ms FAIL
                                                                                                                                                         
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
                                                                                                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'business_categories' already exists (SQL: create table `business_categories` (`id` char
(36) not null, `name` varchar(255) not null, `deleted_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set
 utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                         
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }
                                                                                                                                                         
      +9 vendor frames 
  10  Modules/BusinessService/Database/Migrations/2023_04_08_065850_create_business_categories_table.php:21
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()
                                                                                                                                                         
      +25 vendor frames 
  36  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

#### app\Console\Commands\RunMultipleMigrations.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class RunMultipleMigrations extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'migrate:multiple';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Run migrations from multiple folders in specific sequence ';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations']);
        $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => 'Modules/HRManagement/Database/Migrations']);
        $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => 'Modules/FleetService/Database/Migrations']);
        $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => 'Modules/BusinessService/Database/Migrations']);
        $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => 'Modules/DeliveryService/Database/Migrations']);
        $this->call('migrate', ['--path' => 'Modules/FinanceService/Database/Migrations']);


        $this->info('Multiple migrations of project ran successfully');
    }
}
```

Inside `tinker.php`

```
'commands' => [
        app\Console\Commands\RunMultipleMigrations::class
    ],
```

migration snapshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Another thing to note that issue is happening only on live server when I'm using SSH. In local server, above procedure is working fine

Please let me know if I need to share anything else

#### What I have tried to solved above?

- Caching Issue: Ran php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear.
- Manual Check: Opened your database and see if the table `business_categories` actually exists. But it don't exist
- Ran single migrations
  `php artisan migrate --path=Modules/BusinessService/Database/Migrations/2023_04_07_065850_create_business_categories_table.php` 
  It ran as intended but from where migrate ommand is detecting `2023_04_08_065850_create_business_categories_table` ?

#### UPDATE: Point to ponder

`2023_04_08_065850_create_business_categories_table` this migration don't even exist in the project directory, as I've already shared the screenshots. Main point here is that it is happening only on live server, when running from SSH. I have cleared the cache and all but somehow it is keeping track of old migrations. I mean they were in the project before but I removed them afterwards. This thing also happenned when I tried to run migration of FinanceService folder. `2023_08_10_043908_create_wallet_deductions_table` is not in migration folder but migrate command tried to run it. It was also alse present before.

Comment: One more thing, can you put feedback on each migration, 2nd thing your migration run twice why ? because you have **2023_04_08_065850**_create_business_categories_table and **2023_04_07_065850**_create_business_categories_table different

Comment: @PsyLogic `2023_04_08_065850_create_business_categories_table` this migration don't even exist in the project directory, as I've already shared the screenshots. Main point here is that it is happening only on live server, when running from SSH. I have cleared the cache and all but somehow it is keeping track of old migrations. I mean they were in the project before but I removed them afterwards. This thing also happenned when I tried to run migration of `FinanceService` folder. `2023_08_10_043908_create_wallet_deductions_table` is not in migration folder but migrate command tried to run it.

Comment: Did you try fresh migration

Comment: Yes I removed everything. before running migrations

Comment: Ok can you make a migration status on each Module to see what it's really listing, just to make sure what you have is the same what status will return

Comment: "they were in the project but I removed them" sounds like something wrong with your deployment process.  Have you checked the file system on the server to make sure this file is not there?